# Is there a free/open source wget-like Windows program with graphical progress?

Tags: windows, http, installation, wget

I am writing a WiX-based installer for our software.  I need to download some non-trivial dependencies (like Sql Server Express 2008), then install them.

I could just use wget, but having the console open to show progress could be very confusing for non-technical people.  Instead, I have been looking for a program that works just like wget, but shows its progress in a very simple window with the name of the file and the progress.

If I could show a small message that would be fantastic, but just having the GUI progress is the main thing.

I would even be interested in an existing program that *almost* does this, which I could recompile to add whatever I need.  Since this is in an installer, it can't depend on .Net or anything else that needs installing to work.

Is anyone aware of such a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I did not find such a program, I wrote one.  I used the latest libcurl available for Windows.

The code is not beautiful, and the program is not feature-complete, but it does what I need it to do: download from http:// while displaying a simple, attractive Window.

The titlebar is customizeable on the command-line, and I intend to allow window positioning too.

The project is hosted on google code: http://code.google.com/p/installerget/

Answer (score 1):

Why not to get `wget` [sources](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget) and remove console output from there?

Comment: Better yet, why not use libcurl and write your own UI.  I've looked around and as far as I can tell, no one's bothered to publish such a simple program.  All existing download managers are way over complicated for your needs.

Comment: @scvalex, I was thinking I may need to do just that.  I was hoping to avoid it.

Comment: @jia3ep, I don't want a silent download.  I want the user to know what is happening.  I just don't want it in a console window, since non-technical users will likely be confused by it.

Comment: @Christopher, I don't think that adding some progress bar to wget is a big challenge. There is a `progress.c` file. Just make own implementation of functions in that file.

Comment: @jia3ep, compiling wget from source on windows is not trivial.  In addition, Windows would want to take over the control loop and initialization.  I know it *could* be done, but it's not that simple.  libcurl is a much better option for the roll-your-own route.